# Reboot Machine in GitLab CI Script

Tags: gitlab-ci

I need to reboot a machine (e.g., call `Restart-Computer -Force`) in a GitLab CI script, reestablish contact with the runner, and continue executing the script. The runners are tied to specific machines and execute PowerShell scripts (`shell` executor). How can I do this, and ensure that anything that happens after calling `Restart-Computer` occurs after the machines are rebooted?

Comment: This isn't something that you can do within GitLab CI - restarting will kill the connection to the job which will cause the job to fail. What problem are you trying to solve by rebooting mid-way through the job? If you're attempting to install something on the machine, you should likely use winrm or something similar to remotely access the box instead of using the runner itself in shell mode.

Comment: @Patrick I'm trying to solve two problems simultaneously. First, as you guessed, I'm installing an application. Second, I need to ensure the hardware is in the correct state, since tests aren't independent unless the machines have been rebooted. I'd rather power cycle the machines, so something like WinRM is a good suggestion.

Comment: Yeah, I'd pretty strongly suggest using WinRM - you generally don't want to use your app machine as your runner, since that violates several security principles :)

Comment: @Patrick I ended up rewriting our CI system so that test machines are controlled via SSH, solving both this and a number of other problems simultaneously.